# How to convert normal to uniform in sns pair plot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Code is below

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import StringIO
text = '''id,revenue ,profit,Label
    101,779183,281257,1
    102,144829,838451,1
    103,766465,757565,-1'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text))
df = df[df.columns[1::]]
sns_plot = sns.pairplot(df,hue='Label')
```

My Picture is below

[image]

How to change the normal distribution to uniform distribution in the sns pairplot

Comment: When I use the exact same code, I get revenue and profits for the pairplot, not profit and Label. What do you mean by changing normal distribution to uniform distribution ? Changing distribution implies changing your data.

Comment: @Hugolmn But in sns pairplot the visualization will be in normal distrubuition only even you change your data the graph will be like (1,1)

Comment: It it still not clear to me. What is the expected result, precisely ? Is it about the bottom right graph ? Could you please update the graph according to your code, because when I run it, the result is different.

Comment: @Hugolmn for any data pairplot will show the uniform distribution, is there any way to make the distribution to normal

Comment: You want it for the diagonal or for each plot ?

Comment: @Hugolmn yes, only for diagonal

Comment: So you want to replace the kind of bell curves by histogram ? This is the only other option you have with seaborn